# nothing changes when making change in assets fiels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, precompile

I'm trying to make a change in a css file but it seems that it is not responding to it even if a deleted that whole file, it is still loaded in the page,

I've tried to remove the assets folder from public and made

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

but nothing changed
that's my development config file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.

  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: "Still loaded in the page", what does that mean exactly?  Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: what i mean is that when I inspect the page i still see the deleted file loaded from /assets .. even if i tried to remove that assets folder from public.

Comment: I've tried almost every thing, still got the same issue.